# How to check the string has specific set of character in it or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement to check wether the incoming string has any character and - in the begining?

sample code is:

```
        string name = "e-rob";
        if (name.Contains("[a-z]-"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no match found");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();`
```

The above code is not working. It is not neccessarily e- all the time it could be any character and then -

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using some RegEx:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]-");
bool check = reg.IsMatch("e-rob");
```

Or even more concise:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("e-rob", "^[a-zA-Z]-")) {
    // do stuff for when it matches here
}
```

The `^[a-zA-Z]` is where the magic happens. Breaking it down piece-by-piece:

---

`^`: tells it to start at the beginning of whatever it's checking the pattern against

`[a-zA-Z]`: tells it to check for **one** upper- or lower-case letter between A and Z

`-`: tells it to check for a "-" character directly after the letter

---

So `e-rob` or `E-rob` would both return true where `abcdef-g` would return false

*Also, as a note, in order to use RegEx you need to include*

`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

*in your class file*

[Here's](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) a great link to teach you a bit about RegEx which is the best tool ever when you're talking about matching patterns

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex

```
Regex reg = new Regex("[a-z]-");
if(reg.IsMatch(name.SubString(0, 2))
{...}
```

Comment: Why the `SubString` and not adding a `^` to the beginning of your RegEx pattern?

Comment: Programming is great like that, always a million ways to go about one small thing.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, kind of LINQish:

```
StartsWithLettersOrDash("Test123");

public bool StartsWithLettersOrDash(string str)
{
    string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char [] alphas = (alphabet + alphabet.ToLower()).ToCharArray();
    return alphas.Any(z => str.StartsWith(z.ToString() + "-"));
}
```

Comment: +1 for alternate solutions, although, would this check for a dash directly after the character?

Comment: Errrr, I think that will check for either or, not specifically a letter followed immediately by a dash.

Comment: I misread what the OP wanted. I thought he wanted to check for any letter OR a dash. Not a letter plus a dash. I fixed it